# @FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING) is not working in Junit4 and 5 combined code

Tags: java, selenium, junit, junit4, junit5

Here is the code :

```
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
class TCSix {

    @BeforeAll
    static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @AfterAll
    static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    void aTestBlankEmailValidation() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Test
    void bTestRegistrationORLogin() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }


    }
```

Here the `bTestRegistrationORLogin()` will run first in place of `aTestBlankEmailValidation()`, where as I declared `FixMethodOrder` on top.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change tests execution order in JUnit5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40665216/how-to-change-tests-execution-order-in-junit5)

Comment: @sejal, you should clarify whether you're trying this with JUnit 4 or 5 and update the tags accordingly.

Comment: I am using both combined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is recommended that test methods be written so that they are
>   independent of the order that they are executed

However, for your case, make sure two things:

1. JUnit version is more than 4.11
2. JUnit is not 5 , cause there the annotation is not supported yet

Comment: I am using both JUnit4 and 5 combined.

Comment: in JUnit 4 I have @FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING) and it is working just fine, without any problems. To be sure the annotation cames from it check if it is and then if it is not correct but still not working , give respond here please

Comment: If I will use only JUnit 4 then it will work proper as per you said. But If I will mix both 4 and 5 it will not work. So I can go for JUnit 4 only for now. Thanks.

Comment: JUnit 5 have lots of differences in comparing with JUnit 4 , so I would suggest you to read a bit more about JUnit 5 before switching to it, cause it requires more changes than just including dependency