# Does JUnit 5 support test method execution in alphabetical order or any similar functionality?

Tags: java, junit5

JUnit 4 has `@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)` to support test execution in alphabetical order.

Is there any similar functionality introduced in latest JUnit 5 or any other way to achieve this?

I went through some of the [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40665216/how-to-change-tests-execution-order-in-junit5) but could not find any solution. 
So posting this question again to check for a solution.

Thanks

Comment: Each test should be standalone; neither depend on nor influence other tests.

Comment: @DwB: You are right. But if your run on your development system and fail on your build system, it is really hard to find out which test caused the problem. Enforcing the same order on each build system makes bugs reproducible.

Comment: The failed assert message should identify the test.

Comment: JUnit Jupiter already enforces a consistent order for every test run. So it's already deterministic on all build systems. It's just that you cannot (yet) provide a "custom order".

Comment: Thanks for the valuable input.  @SamBrannen, i have 4 test method in a class (like 1,2,3,4), it always picks in the order 2,1,4,3. Is there any logic behind this order ?

Comment: Yes, there is _logic_ behind the ordering: that's what makes it deterministic.

Comment: That logic can be found here: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/6b7da8949e8b0f93f7e4f7f2b745ae0988474c9a/junit-platform-commons/src/main/java/org/junit/platform/commons/util/ReflectionUtils.java#L1195-L1210

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JUnit issue is still open https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/13
So, right now there is no such possibility.

Comment: The answer is a bit outdated, as there is already a solution in place. Check out the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55626206/1731935

Answer (score 22):

I know I'm late but JUnit5 is capable of that.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestMethodOrder;
        
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.MethodName.class)
public class TestClass{
   //..
}
```

This Annotation is sorting by the actual method name, not the Displayname.

Comment: Thanks, that should be the correct answer. There are some other ordering mechanisms as well, check out `org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer`

Answer (score 12):

Finally, this is now possible.

@TestMethodOrder is avaliable at snapshot version. (5.4)

```
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
class OrderedTestsDemo {

    @Test
    @Order(1)
    void nullValues() {
        // perform assertions against null values
    }

    @Test
    @Order(2)
    void emptyValues() {
        // perform assertions against empty values
    }

    @Test
    @Order(3)
    void validValues() {
        // perform assertions against valid values
    }

}
```

source: [doc](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/TestMethodOrder.html) and [commit](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/commit/5300e650c2662586ecb9f409223ec6bed9d5eae6)

Comment: If you want to run a specific test as a last one, without annotating every test with `@Order`, annotate that single test with `@Order(Integer.MAX_VALUE)`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately at the moment there is currently no mechanism in JUnit5 for ordering the execution of tests.

Comment: Sure it is, check out org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer.Alphanumeric for example.